# Xamarin.Forms Previewer is not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I Install Visual Studio 2017 **version 15.1 (26403.7)** Release. 
also install Xamarin workload, when I create new Xamarin Cross Platform App and open Xamarin.Forms Previewer for render view, Get this error:

> mono.android.DesignerException: md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView.n_onMeasure(II)V
>       at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:43)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:177)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:228)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:693)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
>       at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView.n_onMeasure(II)V
>       at md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView.n_onMeasure(Native Method)
>       at md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView.onMeasure(XFPageRendererView.java:54)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>       at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:545)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:342)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
>       at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:222)
>       ... 4 more

**JDK Version: 1.8.0_121**

[image]

Comment: follow this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77636/xamarin-previewer-error-xfpagerendererview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fix this issue I update Android SDK API 24, [more information](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77636/xamarin-previewer-error-xfpagerendererview)

Answer (score 1):

Right click in your application project xamarin.android. Go to properties and select in using the most recent platform.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most often its due to the Java Development Kit version that needs to be on 1.8 **AND** make sure its the 64-bit version. Then update the JDK location in VS in the options, for me the current location is:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

Comment: my jdk location is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121`  but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, updated the Minimum Android target to 19, rebuilt and restarted VS to resolve the problem.